# Cloning from azure devops using ssh config

Tags: git, azure, ssh, azure-devops

I have more than 2 ssh keys which I use to connect to different servers. To be able to clone from azure devops using ssh I created a ssh key inside `~/.ssh/ad-azure` and linked it in the configuration file as shown below.

```
Host vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
  HostName vs-ssh.visualstudio.com
  User amir
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/ad-azure
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes ssh-rsa
```

now when i use git clone ssh,

`git clone amir@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:v3/test/testProject`

It throws following error.

> Unable to negotiate with 00.74.28.28 port 22: no matching host key
> type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa fatal: Could not read from remote
> repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.

Steps I have followed.

1. Created ad-azure ssh key
2. Added the key to azureDevops "SSH Public Keys"
3. Trying to connect, failing

I already looked into other questions, everything seems ok to me. Can someone spot the issue?

Comment: See https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/not-able-to-clone-git-repo-azuredevops-ssh/1552586):

> The OpenSSH project has removed the public key algorithm ssh-rsa as of [Version 8.8](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8). Currently, Azure Devops still only supports ssh-rsa.
> For a workaround, with the OpenSSH 8.8, you can add the following to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host ssh.dev.azure.com
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

There is [a ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Git-SSH-access-offers-weak-algorithms-r/1547526) requesting the support for a stronger algorithm like sha2.

> This workaround should be considered insecure going forward because, as I mentioned on the February 2020 issue, and as the OpenSSH project has stated repeatedly, [SHA-1 attacks can be accomplished for as little as $50k USD these days](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014.pdf).
>
> Please ensure that the Azure Devops host key is signed according to RFC8332 RSA/SHA-256/512 going forward.